# Download Filtered Data using CGridView Yii

Tags: yii, download, cgridview

I'm using CGridView Widget to show my data. I have a button to download, but I don't know how to do it just with the filtered data.
Any help or guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to save the filtered data in a session variable. This filtered data are in the search function inside the model.

Answer (score 0):

I don't what what you mean by download, may be you are referring to export the data to a file like .xls for example. If this is the case may be you should try using a grid export extension like [EExcelView](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/eexcelview).

I'm the author of the extension so if you have any troubles please let me know, or write an issue in github.

Comment: I can download the data, but I didn't know how to do it using the filters options. I already figured it out, thanks anyway! I going to take a look at your extension.